# Why is Javascript disabled when I'm logged in?

Tags: 7, javascript

Unfortunately I'm not a coder and don't know how to provide info that might solve this riddle.  All I know is that my Flexslider, WYSIWYG fonts, and expand/collapse function do not work (Flexslider is invisible, fonts are a mish-mash rather than @fontyourface standard that is set, and it's as if expand/collapse is not there) when I'm logged in.  I don't have other accounts, but it all works as an anonymous user.  Also, it worked for me as well until a couple of months ago.  Any ideas how that could happen?

Comment: This will be really hard to debug without some errors, particularly browser console errors if any (there probably are).

Comment: The only error I see on reports (and I see a lot of this error) is the following... Notice: Undefined index: stylizer: in ctools_get_plugins() (line 336 of /home/...../.../  I'm not sure if that would relate.  I the error was related to a non-functioning Panels option, that allows the addition of styles (border, shadows, etc.) to your panels.  CSS worked better, so I use CSS.

Comment: *I thought the error was related to a non-functioning Panels option* typo sorry

Comment: is this Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: Are you using any JS aggregation or minifying modules? They can serve different files to authenticated users I believe.

Comment: With your browser, right click and select inspect element then click on console and see if there are any js errors there.

Comment: @NoSssweat Drupal 7

Comment: @NiallMurphy no JS aggregation or minify.

Comment: @NoSssweat.  No JS errors.  I did just discover this issue is occurring in Chrome, but not Firefox.